# In Yolo V8 output models how is the best model selected?

Tags: yolo, yolov8

The output of Yolo V8 gives two models after the completion of specified epochs. best.pt and last.pt. How is the best.pt model selected. The training outputs several graphs and results png but of all the different matrices that it outputs what is used to select the best.pt?